# Dynamic Breakdown Dimension with Mixed Data Type (Text and Number)

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to make a dynamic Breakdown Dimension with mixed Data Type?

[This is the data source sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCxUFNweYcSujp7xbJblxhsg9NEYja6EOgcSKitYJWA/edit?usp=sharing)

[This is the Report I Tried](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/071875b5-d6e5-4602-bbc1-56ddd791b669)

Basically I want the user with view only permission to dynamically change Breakdown Dimension for Q1-Qn chart's with C1-Cn Breakdown Dimension

I tried with the following step:

- Create Parameter `breakdown by parameter`
- Create a Custom Field with this formula:

```
CASE breakdown by parameter
  WHEN "C1" THEN C1 
  WHEN "C2" THEN C2
  WHEN "C3" THEN C3
  WHEN "C4" THEN C4
  WHEN "C5" THEN C5
END
```

- Add Control for the parameter
- Use the custom field in Chart's Breakdown Dimension

But it says `Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER. All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type.`. Is there a workaround for that ? it's working fine if the breakdown dimension is text only or number only.

I also use a control to filter the data, so I want to use control to filter C1-Cn columns and to set breakdown dimension to C1-Cn columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the error message *(emphasis mine)*:

> Invalid formula - THEN/ELSE arguments have incompatible types: TEXT/ NUMBER. **All THEN/ELSE arguments must return the same type**.

Thus (since all but one of the arguments return a TEXT type), one approach is to [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) the only NUMBER field `C2`, `AS TEXT`, so that all values in the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) are text values:

```
CASE breakdown by parameter
  WHEN "C1" THEN C1
  WHEN "C2" THEN CAST(C2 AS TEXT)
  WHEN "C3" THEN C3
  WHEN "C4" THEN C4
  WHEN "C5" THEN C5
END
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a07fa7f2-8b27-453a-a705-704a8303e128) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nWyBdlcY5W1jSJcsvRQed4r46E_XvE2AXhEk28SCJGQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 5]